# Finding the exact position of the bar of the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a margin next to the scrollbar that highlights chapters and other items on a html page. Similar to what eclipse has to show errors, todos etc. (right arrow in this pic) [image]

I can easily calculate the scrollbars relative position within my element using scrollTop, windowHeight and height of the scrollable content. The problem is that this does not take into account that the scrollbar has two small arrows at the top/bottom which makes my algorithm think the scrollbar is slightly taller than it is making the highlight both too large and tending to drift a bit from the center. And i can't find any way of finding the height of these small arrows-buttons.

So the way i see it i need to know either

1. The size of the arrows above/under the scrollbar. I guess this is pretty constant but if possible it would be better to read it in case different browsers use different scrollbars. Especially considering mobile devices which might not have them at all.
2. A direct method of matching scrollposition to a position inside the viewport
3. A way of hiding the arrows completely. (Without reimplementing a scrollbar from scratch using javascript.)

Comment: Well, I'd say make you own scrollbar. You can't know the size of the buttons otherwise. Plus, (as an example) in the latest Mac OS the scrollbars fade away when not in use; in other versions of Mac OS the arrow buttons are grouped at the top or at the bottom of the scrollbar. Or at both ends. Even if you're not targeting Mac OS, the point is that though it's the same OS, the buttons move around, so you can't even hardcode their sizes. And as you say, mobile devices are completely inconsistent.

Comment: Good point about the double arrow button in osx. I think you are right in that i have to create my own scrollbar. The problem is that this will remove alot of accessibility that the OS scrollbar has already invented and trained the user with. I guess showing both the native scrollbar and mine would be the best workaround.

Comment: If the purpose is to make a "link map" of the document along the right edge of the page, is it super-important that it sync with the scrollbar perfectly? You should be able to get a reasonable result by looking at the proportion of the scrollTop property of the node you're trying to link to, and the total height of the document.

Comment: I don't think it will remove a lot of accessibility if you make your own scroll bar.  Have you heard of fleXscroll?  http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar.  You'll still be able to use your mouse, keyboard, and scroll wheel with the scroll bar.  It will act exactly like the browser scrollbar, except you'll have a lot more control over it.  It would work well for you.

Comment: I just gave fleXscroll a shot but just from a one minute test round on their site i found several problems with it, most notably: 1. space/shift+space does not work. 2. pgup/down goes far too long. 3. The mouse wheel scrolling is anything but smooth. 4. It catches more events than it should, ctrl+scroll for example. I came to the conclusion that hiding the original scrollbar and just _displaying_ a custom one was far better, when was the last time you actually dragged the scrollbar with the mouse cursor? If you are really concerned about accessibility, show both your own and the native.